# Installing portainner on ubunto server permission denied

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ssh

So I just installed docker and installed home assistant on docker everything is working but now I want to install **PORTAINER** starting with this command

> docker volume create portainer_data

**And when I press enter it gives me this message get permission denied while trying to connect to the docker daemon socket at unt x:///ver/run/docker and at last it says connect: permission denied
**
What should I do ? Iam new to ubunto and have no experience

I don't know what to do

Comment: If you haven't already done so, explore the website which explains how to Install Portainer with Docker on Linux?  https://docs.portainer.io/start/install/server/docker/linux

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

and

```
sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
```

Also check all docker group users

```
grep /etc/group -e "docker"
```